# Are there equivalents of the Seven Archangels of Zoroastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Tags: persia, ancient-india, hinduism, zoroastrianism

As I explore the possible relationship between archangels in Judaism and Proto-Indo-European religion [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69787/equivalence-between-greco-roman-pantheon-or-proto-indo-european-gods-and-archang), here is a related more specific question.

Zoroastrianism and Early Vedic religion are very similar:

> The religion of Zoroastrianism is closest to Vedic religion to varying degrees. Some historians believe that Zoroastrianism, along with similar philosophical revolutions in South Asia were interconnected strings of reformation against a common Indo-Aryan thread.
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism#Relation_to_other_religions_and_cultures)

Now in Zorastrianism there are seven Archangels called [Amesha Spenta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amesha_Spenta) meaning Holy Immortals.

> Amesha Spenta in the Gathas
> Gathic name – Approximate meaning
>
> 1. Spəṇta Mainyu — Holy/Creative Spirit/Mentality
> 2. [Vohu] Manah — [Good] Purpose
> 3. Aša [Vahišta] — [Best] Truth/Righteousness
> 4. Xšaθra [Vairya] — [Desirable] Dominion
> 5. [Spənta] Armaiti — [Holy] Devotion
> 6. Haurvatāt — Wholeness
> 7. Amərətāt — Immortality

---

Given that Zoroastrianism is highly similar to early Vedic religion: are there equivalents of the Seven Archangels of Zoroastrianism in Vedic Religion?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139057/discussion-on-question-by-hari-kumar-are-there-equivalents-of-the-seven-archange).

Comment: See [Saptarishi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi). This would probably be better suited at [Hinduism.SE](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com), or [Mythology.SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com), seeing as it is mostly about legend, rather than actual history.

Comment: @Lucian its still history as to how religion developed, even though they are myth based.